# How can I give orders to a C# windows application from a website programmed in ASP 3.0

Tags: c#, ms-access, asp-classic

At first look, my question may seem a bit vague. But I'll try to explain it. I am profession in ASP 3.0 programming language and designed a website using ASP 3.0. But I want to build a windows application in C# that checks some data from my website. Unfortunately, I'm a beginner in C# programming and I can't do this job!

In a windows application(programmed in C#), the user must enter a number. This number must be sent to a webpage on my website(and this is my problem). That page connects to the MS Access database (.mdb) and checks the number in database. if that number exists, the windows application user sees a "Granted" message on screen, otherwise another message will appear.

The .asp webpage can be a GET or anything else.
Because I'm a beginner in C#, Please explain in a way I can understand.
I really appreciate your answers.
Iman

Comment: Don't tell me you're teaching your students that it's all right to use Access as a database for a web site? Because that's usually a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a web service. The web application takes a parameter via HTTP GET, and returns a simple web page that indicates whether the number is in the database or not. Then your C# application checks that web page using an WebRequest object. [See here for documentation on how to use WebRequest.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)

Comment: Send the number as a parameter via HTTP GET. So, the parameter is part of the URL request string. For example: `http://www.example.com/getvalue.asp?number=12345`   Does that make sense?

Comment: what is duty of "getvalue.asp" page? I mean after checking the number what should "getvalue.asp" page do? for example redirect to another page or...?

Comment: @charlie-kilian: I found this code on the URL you mentioned:

           `Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            reader.Close ();`


------

What will be value of "responseFromServer" if multiple responses are coming?
For example I want to send this order from my ASP page:

status:granted and a message:you are win

Comment: getvalue.asp should echo the result of its operation. For example, "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE" depending on if the number is found. Then, the C# app reads the response, and checks for "SUCCESS" (if the number is in the database) or "FAILURE" (if the number isn't in the database).

Comment: Think of the web service as a method call. As I've described it, your app would call this web service once per number, and get a result back for that number only. To check another number, it would have to call the web service again. You could always write it differently so that multiple numbers are sent by the C# app and the web service responds with multiple responses. Since you control both sides (the C# app and the web service) you can write it however you want.

Comment: If you end up wanting to use more complicated data, you'll need a common format that both sides use. For example, the C# app might create an XML document, and the ASP app would parse the XML, do whatever is asked of it, and then return a different XML document, which the C# app would then parse. Or instead of XML you might use JSON. Or something else entirely, depending on who will be using the web service. If it is just your application, then I'd go with whatever is easiest to write.

Comment: You said: For example, "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE" depending on if the number is found. if I open `http://www.example.com/getvalue.asp?number=12345` in my browser I should see only "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE" on my screen? What will be happen if I open it in browser?

Comment: If you opened it on your screen and choose View Source, you would see only a text document that has the one word in it. Since it is a web service, it doesn't need to return a full web page. The only thing that will use it is your C# application.

Comment: If you want to be extra-correct about things, you should set the Content/Type of the document to something that indicates that it isn't a web page, like "text/plain". But again, since it is only your application using it, it doesn't really matter so long as your C# app can understand what is sent.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple web request from your C# windows application you'll want to use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class. Set up an instance of the class and call a method on the instance (probably [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx)) to make a request to your web application and get the response as a string.

Of course, you'll need to create a handler in your web application that accepts numbers and returns strings, but since you're proficient in ASP you should be able to do that.

Comment: A query string parameter is probably the easiest way.